# when do I use "do / does + base verb " & "base verb + s ,es , ies" for instance , ( does use) & (uses)?

Tags: difference, do-support

I am always confused when it comes to this type of sentence:

> - She *does use* her car rarely.
> - She *uses* her car rarely.

So, what is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference in meaning between "I play" and "I do play"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-i-play-and-i-do-play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auxiliary *do* is used for emphasis here. It does sound a bit odd with *rarely*, though; a more natural word to use *do* with would be *frequently*.
It would typically stress that something is indeed the case, despite it appearing differently. *We do want to help you* when what you actually do looks like you're not (eg taking a cigarette away from someone).

The technical term is *[emphatic do](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590)*.

See [this page](http://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliaries-do-and-does-for-emphasis) for more examples.